# Why .Net FCL is implementing generic and non-generic interface IList and IList<T> in List<T> class at same time?

Tags: c#, .net

The List is implemented in following manner in .NET
I am surprised why they have implemented generic and non-generic interface in class at same time.

```
[Serializable]
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>,
IList, ICollection, IEnumerable {
public List();
public void Add(T item);
public Int32 BinarySearch(T item);
public void Clear();
public Boolean Contains(T item);
public Int32 IndexOf(T item);
public Boolean Remove(T item);
public void Sort();
public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer);
public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison);
public T[] ToArray();
public Int32 Count { get; }
public T this[Int32 index] { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why not? `IList` and `IList<T>` are not interchangeable, so one does not include the other so to speak.

Comment: Note that the `IList` methods and properties are explicit implementations, so you'll only use them when you type the list as `IList` explicitly. It's mostly for backwards compatibility, to make sure you can use the generic `List<T>` when using libraries made before .NET had generics :)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft made it *very* easy to help .NET programmers forget that COM exists.  This is however not close to reality, COM is alive and well and is still the primary interop technology on Windows.  Just as a recent example, Modern UI in Store and Phone apps are purely COM based under the hood.  Very carefully hidden though, there is practically no way to tell that you are actually using COM when you write a C# app.  Other than the seemingly black magic of effortlessly working with code written in Javascript or C++.

Generics in .NET are an interop problem, it is a pure .NET implementation detail that other non-.NET languages know absolutely nothing about.  So `List<T>` cannot be `[ComVisible(true)]`.

IList, ICollection and IEnumerable to the rescue, interfaces that *are* ComVisible and usable by code written in practically any language on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compatibility issue.
There are many components (e.g., in UI libraries), which use non-generic `IList`, because usage of generic version isn't necessary and often not desirable here.

Consider this WPF sample:

```
var list = new List<MyDataType>();
var collectionView = new ListCollectionView(list);
```

Suppose, that `List<T>` doesn't implement `IList` - you just couldn't use it in this sample. Moreover, imagine, that [`ListCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) must be generic, and try to implement it.

Comment: *Usage of generic version isn't necessary and often not desirable.* Im not sure i agree here. The backwards compatibility issue is primarily because .NET 1.0 didn't support generics.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: in my sample generic `ListCollectionView<T>` ultimately leads to, for example, `ListBox<T>`. Are you sure, that this is what all we need? :)

Comment: Im not sure i understand your comment :\

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: generics requires type arguments. `ListCollectionView` is used by `ItemsControl` in WPF to represent its items. To instantiate `ListCollectionView<T>` with any `T` in `ItemsControl` code, we need `ItemsControl<T>` (and, finally, `ListBox<T>`, since it is inherited from `ItemsControl`). Generic controls?... What for??

Comment: In order to get the proper type `T` when you later want to access that control's items.

Comment: The problem is that you don't need strongly-typed access to control's items. This task is solved by data binding, which is based on reflection.